# Class of CSS element of the background color of wifi selection box in gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell, css

I want to change the background color of the wifi selection box in gnome. However, I don't know which CSS is responsible for the same. Can anybody help me?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You want it for individual while selected for example ldk or ldk to SAJAL??

Comment: `.nm-dialog-item:selected { background-color: blue; color: white; }` is responsible for single line like when you select ldk or SAJAL. I am not sure if you want it that way or entire rectangle from ldk to SAJAL https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfdvI.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y23m.jpg

Comment: @UnKNOWn Thanks. I wanted to change the background color of the whole thing though. But nevermind, I figured it out some hours ago, I'll just post an answer

Comment: @Heisenberg I'd be interested in your solution. Care to share?

Comment: @kanehekili Yeah, sure. I'm sorry forgot to write an answer earlier. You can check out the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to edit a CSS class in order to change the background color of the wifi menu. The class responsible for this was `.nm-dialog-scroll-view`

```
.nm-dialog-scroll-view {
 background: transparent; /* use any color you want */
}
```